# Serial Terminal Programs and Binary Data Logging

Tags: logging, binary, terminal, serial-port

I had a very frustrating experience recently and I don't understand the cause. Using freely available terminal programs (putty, termite, teraterm, etc) on Windows 7 I was configuring them to write the incoming raw binary data to file, but the data was corrupted on review. It turns out, I determined painstakingly, that the logged data had quietlty dropped out binary values 0x00 through 0x08. These data values were *displayed* in binary viewing mode on termite, but without question those same data values were omitted from the log file. My recourse is going to be to write a little python script to log my traffic using pyserial, but I am really bothered by the experience, and would love to understand what was going on here. Can anyone shed insight on the matter?

Comment: Terminals (the actual physical devices) were usually text devices.  Terminal emulator programs also tend to handle just text I/O.  Trying to transfer binary data in a text mode is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Up to me [PCommLite](http://www.moxa.com/product/download_pcommlite_info.htm) is the best freely available serial terminal for WinXX, never had any issues capturing data streams..

Answer (score 0):

Try MuTerm2 https://github.com/edartuz/muterm2
It can capture data in HEX mode